# ¿Como puedo separar datos de un archivo de excel a 2 o mas archivos ascii en genexus 17u2?

Tags: excel, genexus, ascii

¡Buenos dias amigos!

Hoy les traigo una consulta ya que no logro dar con una posible solución.

**HERRAMIENTA**: Genexus 17u2

**REQUERIMIENTO**: Leer un archivo excel, extraer los campos y guardarlos en un archivo ASCII. Separar los registros en 2 archivos independientes: 1 archivo para todo registro que cumpla las validaciones, otro donde se almacenen los archivos que no cumplan las validaciones.

**ELEMENTOS**: Objeto BLOB para subir el archivo excel y un boton (Action) para disparar el proceso

**PROBLEMA**: Las funciones se ejecutan de manera correcta, pero genexus solo crea 1 unico archivo ASCII (registrosIncluidos.asc) y guarda todos los registros en el. Se necesita que los archivos excluidos se guarden en otro archivo, pero genexus ignora su definicion.

**CODIGO DE MUESTRA**

```
Sub 'U_ClickBoton'
 &include = DFWOpen("C:\registrosIncluidos.asc") //Aqui se guardaran los registros buenos
 &exclude = DFWOpen("C:\excluidos.asc") //Aqui se guardaran los registros excluidos
 if &carga.IsEmpty() //validacion que la variable que se alimenta del archivo cargado al BLOB no sea nulo
    msg('Debe de cargar un archivo')
 else
    &Archivo.Source = &Carga
    &RDEP_XLS.Open(&Archivo.GetURI()) //Obtiene la URL del archivo cargado al BLOB

    If &RDEP_XLS.ErrCode <> 0
        Msg('Error de carga')
    Else
        do 'DatosXLS' //ejecuta la funcion de guardado a archivos ASCII
    Endif
endif
EndSub


Sub 'DatosXLS'
 &RDEP_XLS.SelectSheet('Datos')  //Nombre de la hoja de excel
 &Fila = 2          //Comenzar a leer el documento a partir de la linea 2
 &Bandera = 0           //Bandera para indicar si fin de archivo
 Do While &Bandera = 0
    &variable1 = &RDEP_XLS.Cells(&Fila,01).Text.Trim()
        &variable2 = &RDEP_XLS.Cells(&Fila,02).Text.Trim()
    if &variable1 = ''
        &Bandera = 1    //Si la variable 1 es vacia, la bandera se enciende y el DO termina con el siguiente ciclo
        else
            do case
            case &variable2 = ''    //Detectar si la variable 2 es vacia, este registro seria excluido
                do 'escribirExcluidoASC'
            otherwise
                do 'escribirIncluidoASC'    //Este registro es incluido
                &Bandera = 0
        endcase
    endif
    &Fila += 1 //contador para pasar a la siguiente fila
 Enddo
&exclude = dfwclose()  //cerrar el archivo asc de los excluido
&include = dfwclose()  //cerrar el archivo asc de los incluidos
endsub

sub 'escribirExcluidoASC'
 &exclude = dfwptxt(&variable1 + '|' + &variable2 + 'REGISTRO EXCLUIDO')
 &exclude = dfwnext()
endsub

sub 'escribirIncluidoASC'
 &include = dfwptxt(&variable1 + '|' + &variable2)
 &include = dfwnext()
endsub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente, las dos subrutinas 'escribirExcluidoASC' y 'escribirIncluidoASC' te deben quedar de esta forma:

```
Sub 'escribirExcluidoASC'
 &exclude = DFWOpen("C:\excluidos.asc","","",1,"") //Aqui se guardaran los registros excluidos
 &exclude = dfwptxt(&variable1 + '|' + &variable2 + 'REGISTRO EXCLUIDO')
 &exclude = dfwnext()
 &exclude = dfwclose()  //cerrar el archivo asc de los incluidos
EndSub

Sub 'escribirIncluidoASC'
 &include = DFWOpen("C:\registrosIncluidos.asc","","",1,"") //Aqui se guardaran los registros buenos
 &include = dfwptxt(&variable1 + '|' + &variable2)
 &include = dfwnext()
 &include = dfwclose()  //cerrar el archivo asc de los excluido
EndSub
```

Al principio de todo, en Sub 'U_ClickBoton', debes quitar las dos primeras líneas:

```
 &include = DFWOpen("C:\registrosIncluidos.asc") //Aqui se guardaran los registros buenos
 &exclude = DFWOpen("C:\excluidos.asc") //Aqui se guardaran los registros excluidos
```

Y en el sub 'DatosXLS', debes quitar las últimas líneas:

```
&exclude = dfwclose()  //cerrar el archivo asc de los excluido
&include = dfwclose()  //cerrar el archivo asc de los incluidos
```

Con eso debería funcionarte correctamente. Este parámetro 1 que se le pasa a la función DFWOpen sirve para indicarle que si el archivo ya existe no lo pise, sino que abra el existente para continuar su procesamiento.

Comment: Funciono de maravilla, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Era exactamente lo que se ocupaba.

Answer (score 0):

Para leer un documento Excel puedes usar el tipo `&ExcelDocument`.
Para escribir en un archivo tienes el tipo `&File.AppendAllText(&linea,Encoding.ASCII)`